# CSS Columns break border between columns

Tags: html, css

Please reference [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtcb6muy) for a demo for my question.

TL;DR: I'm looking for a way for the purple border to go as high as the green border (so that the purple border masks the green by overlap). I'm looking for any creative solution, hacks included.

More specifically, for this application in the `<section>` box there is a `<ul>` which is populated dynamically varying amounts of items. The design approved by the client has a space in the horizontal top-border between the columns. Because the amount of items in the list varies I'm avoiding using `<div>`s with floats for columns. I can't find any CSS rules for this and all the other articles I've read are about how to create vertical borders (which I have made purple in the demo for an easy visual), but I can't determine if it's possible to make those borders overlap the parent's outer border.

Edited for clarity 2015-09-27 17:29 UTC-5

Comment: Please *"suppress the green border"* ... *"gap..."* What does that means?

Answer (score 0):

Using the "column-rules" property familly doesn't appear to offer what you need.
In my opinion, I would do something like the fiddle below. I agree, it's not very optimised for semantic, and it will not works alone for managing the columns number.

Maybe you can make something in PHP to change the columns number regarding the number of items before generationg your page.
If you're not working with PHP, a little JS function can do the formatting for you :)

```css
/*.list-group > li {
  list-style: none;
}

section.row > div {
  margin: 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;  
  border: solid 4px #88d0cd;
  border-right: solid 4px #FF00FF;
}

section > div:last-child {
 border-left: none;
}

section > div:not(:last-child) {
 border-left: none;
}*/


.row {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.row > .col {
  float : left;
  width: 30%;
}

.col > ul {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
    border-top: solid 4px #88d0cd; 
    border-bottom: solid 4px #88d0cd; 
}

.col:first-child {
  border-left: solid 4px #88d0cd;
}

.col:last-child {
  border-right: solid 4px #88d0cd;
}

.col:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: solid 4px #FF00FF;  
}

.col:not(:last-child) > ul {
  border-right: none;  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a fine solution, but I was trying to accomplish that without using ```<div>```s with floats assigned to them such that the text flows and is automatically balanced between columns. Doesn't look like that's possible though.